# Does $|e^z| = e^x$ for $z = x + yi$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Geometrically, I understand that $e^z = e^{x + yi} = e^x e^{yi}$ implies that $arg(e^z) = y$.  But does this also imply that $|e^z| = e^x$?

Answer (score 4):

$|e^z| = |e^{x+iy}| = |e^xe^{iy}| = e^x|e^{iy}| = e^x$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
e^z &= e^x (\cos y + i \sin y) \\
\left| e^z \right| &= \sqrt{e^{2x} \cos^2 y + e^{2x}\sin^2 y} \\
&= e^x \sqrt{\cos^2 y + \sin^2 y} \\
&= e^x.
\end{align*}

Also, you should be careful--$\arg e^z$ is only equal to $y$ when $y \in (-\pi, \pi]$ (or whatever branch you're using for the $\arg$ function.)

Comment: Explain the downvote, please?? T_T